# Changing Date format and appending to original file

Tags: shell-script

I have file like this called a.txt:

```
[2016-03-30T04:51:51.599-04:00]!ER_DEV!Port_Conflict!/u05/app/
[2016-01-20T04:30:21.885-04:00]!ER_DEV!Port_Conflict!/u05/app/
```

I need to modify it so it looks like:

```
  2016-03-30 04:51:51!ER_DEV!Port_Conflict!/u05/app/
  2016-01-20 04:30:21!ER_DEV!Port_Conflict!/u05/app/
```

i already wrote a command to change [2016-03-30T04:51:51.599-04:00] to 2016-03-30 04:51:51 .but how to append the query output to original file.

```
  awk -F'!' '{print $1}' a.txt | awk -F '[T.]' '{print $1 " " $2}' | awk '{gsub(/\[/,"")}1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how strict you want to be with your pattern matching.  If you're not too concerned about "rogue data" then a simple-ish `sed`

```
sed 's/^\[\(....-..-..\)T\(..:..:..\).......:..]/\1 \2/'
```

If you have a version of `sed` that knows about the `-i` flag then you can do an in-place update of the file

```
sed -i 's/^\[\(....-..-..\)T\(..:..:..\).......:..]/\1 \2/' a.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy done with **sed**

```
sed '
    s/T/ /      #exchange "T" by "space"
    s/\[/ /     #exchange "[" by "space"
    s/\..*\]//  #remove from "." till "]" included
    ' a.txt
```

But if you prefer **awk**

```
awk -F'[][]' '
    {
        split($2, a,"[T.]")
        $2=a[1]
        $3=a[2] $3
        print
    }
    ' a.txt
```

Comment: That works assuming there is no capital `T` or `[]`'s in the error message.

Comment: It shouldn't matter; the search stops on the first T which is part of the timestamp.  It does assume a good timestamp, though :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris, Good point. Didn't think about that.